# Static library button clicked issue

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, ios7, static-libraries

I have created my static library with having xib files, but application crash when I clicked on any button which are present into static library views.

thanks in advance

Comment: no crash log… @MidhunMP

Comment: Check that button action is connected are not.

Comment: @PiyushDubey I have created my static library those having some buttons when I clicked on that app crashes. I have taken Button either dynamically or in Xib both doesn't work...

Comment: @Romance those are connected and I have TableView too on it didSelectedRowAtIndex delegate doesn't called too…..

Comment: May be class refernce check it or check any userinteraction state of that button.

Comment: Show the button click event code.

Comment: Until you post the stacktrace of the crash, this issue cannot be resolved.

Comment: It may depend on the way you are creating instances of your static library. If your library is a controller, then you have to retain the instance of your library, otherwise your interface will be displayed BUT any controls won't work.

Comment: @SavaMazăre I am using the ARC classes, My both code static Library and the target project both are ARC.

Comment: it does not matter in some cases, jus show us how you instantiate and present the static library, post some code

Comment: @SavaMazăre as I have clicked on the any button the application crashes when I have add via(addSubview) that view/class'sView which I have created from the Static Library, but If I used the presentViewController than the application doesn't crash. What the issue for adding the view here.

Comment: Look, do you really think I (we) could solve your problem without a piece of code provided? I am not Nostradamus, I have to see the way you present the library component.